# How to keep my C program from terminating when CTRL-C is pressed?

Tags: linux, process, signals

AFAIK this has something to do with "catch the SIGINT" but I'm looking for more details. Like many others I learn C by writing my own CLI that can start other program located by the environment variables. My shell can start other processes in the foreground and in the background but how can keep background process running and my shell running when CTRL-C is pressed to terminate the foreground process? Part of my code is:

```
    int main() {
    /*... builtin commands and i/o ...*/
    isBackground = 0;
    for (b = 0; b<max; b++) {
        if ('&'==line[b])   {
            isBackground = 1;
        }
    }
    if (isBackground == 1)  {   /*If backgroundprocess*/
        printf("Background process\n");
        take_return=pipe(fd);  /*(two new file descriptors)*/
        pid_temp = fork();
    }
    else if (isBackground == 0) {   /*If foreground process*/
        printf("Foreground process\n");
        if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/
            printf("Signal foreground\n");
            sigemptyset(&my_sig); /*empty and initialising a signal set*/
            sigaddset(&my_sig, SIGCHLD);    /*Adds signal to a signal set (my_sig)*/
            /*http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html*/
            sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
        }
        pid_temp = fork();
        foreground = pid_temp;  /*Set pid for foreground process*/
    }
    else if (0>pid_temp)    {
        /*Error*/
    }
    else    {
        /*Child process*/
        if (1 == isBackground)  {   /*Backgroundprocess*/
            dup2(fd[STDIN_FILENO], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);
        }
        /*http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?execvp+2*/
        if (execvp(argv2[0],argv2) < 0) {
            printf("We are sorry to inform you that something went wrong %d \n", errno);
        }
    }
    if (0 == isBackground) {    /*Foregroundprocess*/
        waitpid(foreground, &status, 0);    /*Waiting*/
        printf("Foreground process id %d\n", foreground);
        /*Foregroundprocess terminated*/
        /*FIXME*/
        gettimeofday(&time_end, NULL);
        time = (time_end.tv_sec-time_start.tv_sec)*1000000 + time_end.tv_usec-time_start.tv_usec;
        printf("Execution time %ld ms\n", time);
        /*TODO Print out the execution time*/
        /*      int isSignal = 0;*/ /*FIXME*/
        if (1 == isSignal)  {   /*If using signaldetection*/
            int a = sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &my_sig, NULL);
            /*http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html*/
            if (0 == a) {
                /*Sigprocmask was successfull*/
            }
            else    {
                /*Sigprocmask was not successfull, return=-1*/
            }
            Janitor(SIGCHLD);
        }
        /*TODO Print how long time was the total execution time*/
    }
    else if (1==isBackground)   {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }
}
/* pid= fork();
 if(pid==0) {
     execvp(progpath,argv);
     fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp\n");
 } else {
     wait(NULL);
     printf("Child exited\n");
 }*/
built_in_command = 0;   /*Reset*/
memset(line, 0, sizeof line); /*Reset*/
}
return (0);

}
```

Comment: You already seem to be able to process signals (you catch and act upon `SIGCHLD`), so you just have to add a handler for `SIGINT` the same way and do whatever you want in that handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a function, called a "signal handler". It has a very specific type. Then you need to change your code to "install the signal handler". It's probably best to do this with teh `sigaction(2)` system call. So, something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
void sighandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *);

...

void
sighandler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *vp)
{
    write(2, "Received SIGINT\n", 16);
}
```

Inside `main()`, before your program does anything time consuming:

```
struct sigaction sa, osa;

sa.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, &osa);
```

You may want to check the return value of `sigaction()` for an error. Once you include the signal handler function, and get code to install it executed before a control-C happens, congratulations, you've got a signal handler install.

Other consequences to your code exist. Some system calls (`read()`, `close()` to name two) will return an error (-1) and set `errno` to EINTR. Reads on sockets are particularly prone to this. So, to avoid problems like losing track of open file descriptors, and missing data from sockets, you need to have code to handle EINTR situations.

Comment: Don't forget to *carefully* read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Often, a signal handler should only set some `volatile sigatomic_t` flag to be tested elsewhere.